# Como hacer que mi variable tipo string se "tokenize" para llevarla a una matriz por delimitadores?

Tags: c++, variables, matriz

tengo una pregunta bastante importante para mí y es llevar un texto tipo string a un chart o una matriz utilizando delimitadores y sin depender de archivos de texto externos al programa.

mi variable

```
std::string
```

quiero convertirla en una matriz tipo

```
Matriz[50][11];
```

Las columnas estan delimitadas por "()" y los valores por ",".

ya probe con poner la variable directamente asi

```
Matriz [50][11] = {mistring}
```

pero no lo lee.

el texto de la variable es este:

```
((1664142300000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000078","792711162.0",1664142599999,"615.63636645",6,"524877171.0","409.40419338","0"),(1664142600000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","1083374165.0",1664142899999,"834.63467174",7,"43656469.0","34.05204582","0"),(1664142900000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","1793888995.0",1664143199999,"1381.42273128",9,"12820513.0","10.00000014","0"),(1664143200000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","812978737.0",1664143499999,"626.28208902",13,"28846153.0","22.49999934","0"),(1664143500000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","3534042850.0",1664143799999,"2721.41436800",10,"20137350.0","15.70713300","0"),(1664143800000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","2591404144.0",1664144099999,"1996.85562632",28,"147443544.0","115.00596432","0"),(1664144100000,"0.00000077","0.00000077","0.00000077","0.00000077","331182501.0",1664144399999,"255.01052577",8,"0.0","0.00000000","0"),(1664144400000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","87557783612.0",1664144699999,"68293.44762538",21,"87395424414.0","68168.43104292","0"),(1664144700000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000078","24306459448.0",1664144999999,"18952.98164975",24,"23700787479.0","18486.61423362","0"),(1664145000000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","45471351441.0",1664145299999,"35466.19023641",23,"45324962684.0","35353.47089352","0"),(1664145300000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","2330365210.0",1664145599999,"1794.88406780",8,"50285610.0","39.22277580","0"),(1664145600000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000078","1572485667.0",1664145899999,"1223.99887241",17,"1318490882.0","1028.42288796","0"),(1664145900000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000078","6531880747.0",1664146199999,"5031.63913456",8,"209095937.0","163.09483086","0"),(1664146200000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000078","44793889.0",1664146499999,"34.93923342",3,"44793889.0","34.93923342","0"),(1664146500000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000078","673396919.0",1664146799999,"521.77792197",6,"326229434.0","254.45895852","0"),(1664146800000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000078","361287463.0",1664147099999,"281.80422114",6,"361287463.0","281.80422114","0"),(1664147100000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","181560445.0",1664147399999,"140.68615802",4,"88461537.0","68.99999886","0"),(1664147400000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","431579338.0",1664147699999,"335.65070563",5,"333461537.0","260.09999886","0"),(1664147700000,"0.00000077","0.00000077","0.00000077","0.00000077","36838351.0",1664147999999,"28.36553027",1,"0.0","0.00000000","0"),(1664148000000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","2056561414.0",1664148299999,"1584.09175175",8,"53946297.0","42.07811166","0"),(1664148300000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","225140546.0",1664148599999,"175.07904075",5,"172082033.0","134.22398574","0"),(1664148600000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000078","65465368.0",1664148899999,"50.56161320",2,"15327984.0","11.95582752","0"),(1664148900000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","429934524.0",1664149199999,"332.32648501",6,"127690153.0","99.59831934","0"),(1664149200000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","53816940.0",1664149499999,"41.56737713",2,"12833333.0","10.00999974","0"),(1664149500000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","63159912.0",1664149799999,"48.77947391",4,"14634167.0","11.41465026","0"),(1664149800000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000078","97178650.0",1664150099999,"75.31994832",5,"49238782.0","38.40624996","0"),(1664150100000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","2865573852.0",1664150399999,"2234.63636101",6,"2814449497.0","2195.27060766","0"),(1664150400000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000078","801441506.0",1664150699999,"624.59368756",8,"748372794.0","583.73077932","0"),(1664150700000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","130790027.0",1664150999999,"101.72898186",4,"102066107.0","79.61156346","0"),(1664151000000,"0.00000078","0.00000079","0.00000077","0.00000079","62743166942.0",1664151299999,"48940.17398476",67,"53539586356.0","41761.87735768","0"),(1664151300000,"0.00000078","0.00000079","0.00000078","0.00000078","95039254.0",1664151599999,"74.49141203",4,"36079391.0","28.50271889","0"),(1664151600000,"0.00000079","0.00000079","0.00000078","0.00000079","1167169476.0",1664151899999,"918.80394507",8,"841175379.0","664.52854941","0"),(1664151900000,"0.00000079","0.00000079","0.00000078","0.00000078","147230519.0",1664152199999,"115.14096424",2,"30115942.0","23.79159418","0"),(1664152200000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000078","0.0",1664152499999,"0.00000000",0,"0.0","0.00000000","0"),(1664152500000,"0.00000079","0.00000079","0.00000078","0.00000078","1959017214.0",1664152799999,"1528.32394270",3,"29051578.0","22.95074662","0"),(1664152800000,"0.00000079","0.00000079","0.00000078","0.00000078","62623672.0",1664153099999,"49.23197111",3,"38550695.0","30.45504905","0"),(1664153100000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000078","108946798.0",1664153399999,"84.97850244",1,"0.0","0.00000000","0"),(1664153400000,"0.00000079","0.00000079","0.00000079","0.00000079","104351953.0",1664153699999,"82.43804287",3,"104351953.0","82.43804287","0"),(1664153700000,"0.00000079","0.00000079","0.00000078","0.00000078","45175286922.0",1664153999999,"35237.34232008",12,"61852092.0","48.86315268","0"),(1664154000000,"0.00000078","0.00000079","0.00000078","0.00000078","77528176625.0",1664154299999,"60472.58067225",22,"60290475.0","47.62947525","0"),(1664154300000,"0.00000079","0.00000079","0.00000077","0.00000078","43066147394.0",1664154599999,"33591.65872788",16,"122800297.0","96.00499222","0"),(1664154600000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","837623806.0",1664154899999,"651.97312678",11,"700279616.0","546.21810048","0"),(1664154900000,"0.00000077","0.00000077","0.00000077","0.00000077","0.0",1664155199999,"0.00000000",0,"0.0","0.00000000","0"),(1664155200000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","1688829428.0",1664155499999,"1313.59733499",5,"1319867543.0","1029.49668354","0"),(1664155500000,"0.00000077","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000077","189482145.0",1664155799999,"146.28497010",3,"38371845.0","29.93003910","0"),(1664155800000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000078","444371180.0",1664156099999,"345.57488025",13,"340907165.0","265.90758870","0"),(1664156100000,"0.00000078","0.00000078","0.00000077","0.00000078","96967877.0",1664156399999,"74.98706015",4,"32179486.0","25.09999908","0"),(1664156400000,"0.00000078","0.00000079","0.00000077","0.00000079","103512167618.0",1664156699999,"80739.49929059",42,"97203323622.0","75819.81695345","0"),(1664156700000,"0.00000079","0.00000079","0.00000079","0.00000079","39515189.0",1664156999999,"31.21699931",1,"39515189.0","31.21699931","0"),(1664157000000,"0.00000079","0.00000079","0.00000079","0.00000079","0.0",1664157299999,"0.00000000",0,"0.0","0.00000000","0"))
```

tampoco le pude sacar el doble parentesis... use esto para reemplazar los valores:

```
std::replace(DATA.begin(), DATA.end(), ']', ')'); #include <algorithm>
```

---

Yo hice este hace un rato probando y jugando, pero por alguna razón no me funciona, sería más que nada para seguir aprendiendo porque el código de PaperBirdMaster me funcionó:

```
std::string mvalores [50] [12];
//convetir string en tabla pasando las letras a char y luego designarlas a una casilla de la matriz concatenando la variable actual con el nuevo char hasta llegar al delimitador               

std::string from4 = ",";
std::string::size_type pos4 = 0;
std::string concatenacion;
int da = 0;
       
for (int fils = 0; fils <= 50; fils++){

    for (int cols = 0; cols <= 12; cols++){
    pos4 = DATA.find(from4, pos4) < std::string::npos;

        for (int da; da < pos4, da++;){          
        concatenacion = concatenacion + DATA[da];//designar concatenacion a matriz.
        } 

    mvalores [fils][cols] = concatenacion;
    std::replace(mvalores [fils][cols].begin(), mvalores [fils][cols].end(), ',', '\0');
    concatenacion = "";
    std::cout << mvalores [fils][cols] << std::endl;

    }
}
```

Los valores no se muestran en las casillas de la matriz...

Comment: No es así de simple. Tienes que pensar en un algoritmo. Hay diferentes formas de resolverlo. Por ejemplo, puedes recorrer el string caracter por caracter, actuando de acuerdo a él. O ayudarte de [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: interesante forma de verlo, muchas gracias por escribirme, buscare como hacer el algoritmo, no lo encontré en internet ni se cómo hacerlo pero más que nada es eso, agradecido de la idea. gracias por todo

Answer (score 0):

Separa el proceso en dos partes:

1. Obtener cada grupo de valores.
2. Obtener cada valor del grupo de valores.

Lo primero puedes hacerlo con una `std::regex`, lo segundo con un `std::stringstream`:

```
using string_collection = std::vector<std::string>;

string_collection split(const std::string &text, const std::regex &r)
{
    return {std::sregex_token_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), r, 1), std::sregex_token_iterator()};
}

string_collection split(const std::string &text, char separator = ',')
{
    std::stringstream reader(text);
    string_collection result;
    std::string token;

    while (std::getline(reader, token, separator))
        result.push_back(token);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<string_collection> Matriz;

    for (const auto &token : split(data, std::regex{R"(\(([0-9.,"]+)\))"}))
        Matriz.emplace_back(std::move(split(token)));

    std::cout << "Matriz[" << Matriz.size() << "][" << Matriz[0].size() << "]\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVldb9xGEny2fsWCByS7uA0xPT0z3W07/gf3ktfYMDYyzxYirwRplQti@Lf7qvmxO0vd2Y4oAbbIGZLFnurq6uHl7e1Pl9e7/fsvX/5xtb@8fnjXrV5e3dwf7rrdx1cXp3N/dJeHm7v6DOZc7d/XZ@66992fry4uLm/294fV/eHd8@fDpNW73WG3@nn1S7Ner6mURCly8J9tE9r@jyDSVAfafG1ELAoRldiGZjveL5v/bJtCuS2M35Jysy3bJsekIiTkk5sUrE0hkTH3z2g22wlReSIiP6CgzJKo5AqSjpCUEyClAhCp2QpAcMklFesRYTDkGFLWOANkSwCJsSoQVICYRkDESm2KUZgibuNnosaQiXtENN2J0jkijgsQKUUTFZYKUJoWLZbWEagFBIF420TVhKUcAMXYDjN5DigvAMSZwYSoOVSIZEQUJSJEOFE0@CieEQOx8DC7AcskCDH76BkkXQAJLCZnZ0onSGDsuGpmpdWcESxGlKLiVJKEIAzTGwKoELKVxDMqJfoqqK8fMBNpzIEqTDyFKeORBP5mn6r9ldX18@DgZWY49G8QSDKeolyoyntk0UghjcZtSlJi9tSO5Few5RTx@kOAilLRFnmAZbd5iOSJ0HwkJg7QG0tJK2g2LZxajq3h4ckEohQTrmDxayXJoAKkSUtbXBi5zKANJH9i1FJOoGl2Dpyg5ThCA3dKaQlpxzgPaOxXcEwGlukQNeQJ8hDxUeM8h8ZL2I7sgRJGqhIwTzoOAUstRCAU0dBTKwfkahkmN2xthIBJ1hnFcllQWCgLqkUupRKpPMk4xcitmSrmIFQkLqRYNwuqcRTOqK6rmGJlBssW0KtkPEcDyHKCVSYxz4EJ5cWI8e59oGKwYNkGpW2oQEQtKQedYSrx@zE9OkDCeIWxCtGk5qhoxobVTWALn089HzxDk5dESJitGNVwJikHwVoReAYy6R0BxxKjJR7oHXNqfZGzzslddEF8XKaQ3oVPiGRS8ojyq9CgSF5hy2zybLhGJLRACUgJyZFS5Qhk0nFUnbYoCq56AYY@jeVXRt1s@3k6Z5CkBekPHc7iPqzCM6k5M1xcDhJy4Wab/QRXgODV2vC/EcmSSleUFVpZAbLjkrWQKshdxET6Vp3TsEQW8dLQubFojTecBBsrhNNGkslLicsiGzLZhsAkCJGoe@NZXHSRUEfUj4BSUQE66TT4JBZScDzZT8DHxcCjl0SWQTdNs8y4rEuEugBMxnJVgPSohy2iVwhmFfXMI8ZRTCeL1FqG05Z5rqstqbHRrSkajRMcoyOTYwvBQcAC9blOESwPk7U1a7MpnPnc2lpcAAgOiIqlqq7aJM6wARlqiY6Ih/BEdC7MlfP3efPFsiVGuyDRzWrXZpM2wy9BmV2HqJcdiC6ji5JpsYa6EGdkNl1AHUMbpqUy/TlMugwqe4@EZIk9lbEIrDIWd@gUzAic0ay0Y10XrFQElCyM2lPhObrr2HeO@KWRPCgNMNFYzFEHCf1dlFCClDmqtCBGGtwv5lAqUEejDZrDXBTY8cFuCOIl0e2aQ8rKrTDuabMmxNV8QfFiFxmob4Xo6K/Rmgi6bSWvBqn3YaEgZkOQ4LALWiPvwM8B0dd9tf1fQD5SoqCAFWRZtXIUj7z27CPwWlHUsHTiSQmpzlo4l0GrSQoKvaCnlKIzaPz90B5F0ZxBbmtOuCa1FngdtJgEfe4jxWAO7BiNvqNFrgmsps3QPJJq@z401mdxERcjqchEk1gbKawOKhjY0ZNJE6Gi8NgVYXKb4frBeJpBsidC6m1@ksghV24RHnEiE5poFDs00TH1AskBp8ZVRsvSivkhzRYsLvHSlRbFSadraxG@4TfQfi@JBnqFgKpd@Y0c5eg33PmggCfITO/moyFyWXTamQHb4FxnPSuuWoAIvSf6UakSiyeJTuj7oNG@/dejgXK6NOVBogOcPJQPCM/RMC1YHULj692EVnAmhYatMEFpjyl92xb6ftN3B@XRAYUEa2qZKxiTJqNE@cZTQhPRR@Vs7vnoGR5ZsEjJHSjKl8V6ney4sRDh1dHk@Z4hplP0rVmUuWBDJqHyqxuDOJe@FBZInzgk6GqJpy4np0mV0f2AVOhxwK3oGzEOKoDQSQYCocGGlcZRnBEo8fdH6lE19c2h0jdbVYalfGp1oL8lK2qoeqR6j@j5M5l6g3KC1Aj0LMlSWbKdxoIs07rGp0mWC3og893h4jchEFu89hp89VDk0QpE9JOANV89W9B/VTqY6Sk6mJdsUFNRRZ@FNKlgpOOWOTFsj7DvWQ99DmRIi4Aa096PobYWtJA5zVAtMc8olej@qOra4RePXbtvm8MMwoKOasgo38NcCHVroC2q@zxKumCnBfYTzyCt1qqE48ZPbtHnqQbPH9/Gh@JZkPGzCNr23OIwq8oMUqEFkKwYeCqVNSx88jum7o8pD34n@r6ilnHnZ9hEsDAjcUkLjCEFSG@E6YHcVYiOUh2gA/45w@so5qfoLYn3yyh5g5SiD1F4E2/hUDJmSlRkQQ2B/@zNV4XrKNiEjPYjpr6S1VPPB2s0EhagqSgk8e@k@2bTvLi4eLj3T4vDF8a3lzfX193l4epmv/p5@PQ4fLF8WX2GfIWLHk@/v72@Oqwff7P84dD9ediuqoH@@@bqh7vNxaeLZ3fd4eFuv/o0XNIPvT3c/N7t314dursdHr32G7S/de@v9uvNdtUfdft3/vfddkX47yvXbj6/uPj8FLgfdner@@52198Gsfhx@2OPt5o7fN1d4Z933YBy88InzB91190/XB9enF276nEikM/@8@Hqulut@7H33eH6at@th1tuh0nbE47N5uLZs@F27e3D/Ye3v@0uf1/3szZ@rzGY0wPx4lf7w@rjziN3BH9c0BnOV6t/7XDuL7/Rv/HOY3B2D4cbRMWfsXo@hs2/Q2@rxfz0S7N@vV7/Gn6ydtu8@efmNaj1uUc73LPtPt5e7y67AXB/4cebP7r1cLvhBTb9K/RjlzcPh9XLl6tmuPrXxg/GO91f/dWtN/3om3rg1/DmbOz1vqlCEhCNL1/@Cw)</kbd>.

Comment: WOOOOOOOO TE RE PASASTE!, ME FUNCIONO PERFECTO! muchisisisisisisimas gracias de verdad, estaba re plantado y me ayudaste un montonazo, no sé cómo agradecerte! la gente como tu vale oro x 999... de verdad muchísimas gracias. alto programador!